# Why doesn't my Perl code work when I put it in a foreach loop?

Tags: perl, foreach

This code outputs the scalars in the row array properly:

```
  $line = "This is my favorite test";
  @row = split(/ /, $line);

  print $row[0];
  print $row[1];
```

The same code inside a foreach loop doesn't print any scalar values:

```
  foreach $line (@lines){
      @row = split(/ /, $line);
      print $row[0];
      print $row[1];
  }
```

What could cause this to happen?

I am new to Perl coming from python.  I need to learn Perl for my new position.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure that `@lines` is properly initialized? (Also, maybe you're declaring variables elsewhere, but these snippets would fail to run with `use strict;`)

Comment: When you write `split / / ...` or `split /\s+/ ...`, it's almost always better to use `split " " ...` instead. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: Note that in Perl the `print` builtin takes a list as an argument, and slices are possible as well, so you could simplify your code by writing `print @row[0..1]` or `print @row[0,1]`.  Doing `print ...; print ...;` is ok but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: See [perldoc print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) for full information on it.  (In fact, I recommend using [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/) every time you encounter something new, it answers tons of newbie questions right off the bat.)

Comment: You may get helpful error messages if you use `use strict; use warnings;`, which should be used in *every* perl script and module.

Comment: Always show minimal but complete programs. We can't help you with seeing everything that you are doing, as Jefromi pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in Jefromi's comments, whatever the problem is, it exists outside of the code you posted. This works entirely fine:

```
$lines[0] = "This is my favorite test";

foreach $line (@lines) {
    @row = split(/ /, $line);
    print $row[0];
    print $row[1];
}
```

The output is `Thisis`

Answer (score 0):

When I run into these sorts of problems where I wonder why something in a block is not happening, I add some debugging code to ensure I actually enter the block:

```
 print "\@lines has " . @lines . " elements to process\n";
 foreach my $line ( @lines )
      {
      print "Processing [$line]\n";
      ...;
      }
```

You can also do this in your favorite debugger by setting breakpoints and inspecting variables, but that's a bit too much work for me. :)

If you need to learn Perl and already know Python, you shouldn't have that much trouble going through [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001322) in a couple of days.